# How to export an interface from a module using typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There seems to be no accepted answer to this and I'm failing with my search skills to get the answer. I'm following along with a tutorial that has no problems with this so I assume it's an ES version thing.

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/repositories/inmemorytaskrepo.ts:1:27 - error TS2306: File 'project/src/repositories/taskrepo.ts' is not a module.
```

The file I'm calling this from is `/src/repositories/inmemorytaskrepo.ts`

```
import { ITaskRepo } from "./taskrepo";
import { Task } from "../models/task";

export class InMemoryTaskRepo implements ITaskRepo {
}
```

My `/src/repositories/taskrepo.ts` looks like this

```
import { Task } from "../models/task";

export interface ITaskRepo {
    getAll(): Promise<Task[]>;
    get(taskId: number): Promise<Task>;
    create(task: Task): Promise<Task>;
    update(taskId: number, task: Task): Promise<Task>;
    delete(taskId: number): Promise<Task>;
}
```

I believe I'm exporting it correctly and also importing the interface correctly. What could possibly be wrong with this?

Comment: I don't get that error with [this code](https://github.com/md2perpe/stackoverflow-66589614).

Comment: Can you show us your tsconfig and how you are invoking the tool that throws this error?